# Read and Write to Window Registry in window xp and 7

Tags: windows-7, vb6, windows-xp, registry

I'd like to read and write window registry in **window xp and 7** by using **vb6**. I'm not much strong in vb6. I tried this below

```
Dim str As String
str = GetSetting("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines", "Text", "ImportMixedTypes")
```

My coding doesn't work. Please point out my missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `GetSetting` for that setting. That method is only for reading/writing configuration settings for your own application. If you want to read anywhere in the registry you have to use the Windows API function [RegOpenKeyEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724897%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and friends.

Here's a Microsoft support article that explains how to do this (with sample code): [How To Use the Registry API to Save and Retrieve Setting](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/145679)

Note that you will have to have permission to read the relevant place in the registry, I'm not 
sure if you'll have access to that key so you'll have to try it out.

Comment: You probably *shouldn't* have permissions to access that key. Anything in `HKLM` should require UAC's approval.

Comment: Thanks @ho1. Now it works. Here is [free sample code](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=36731&lngWId=1)

Comment: Yes, only for writing. But the question says "reading and writing", so it's bound to cause problems when you start doing the "and writing portion". :-)

Answer (score 0):

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE can cause permission problems. described in these article [Microsoft API article](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/kb/145679)

procedures works well if you will change HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE to CURRENT_USER.